# CSS não se sobrepõe

Tags: css, wordpress

Mesmo usando !important, não consigo aumentar o font-size do texto deste formulário. Já experimentei colocar font-size:

- no custom CSS (opções do tema) que estou usar
- no CSS do plugin (Gravity Forms)

E nenhum deles funcionou. Como é que posso aumentar o tamanho de letra neste formulário específico? Obrigado.

https://designportugal.net/questionario-duas-perguntas/

Comment: Coloca seu código

Comment: pelo inspector do browser eu consegui mudar, certeza que nao tem outra regra sobrescrevendo?

Comment: Estou colocando isto (no Custom CSS do tema) mas não funciona: http://pastebin.com/xGt4Gi4V

Comment: @leofontes, também consigo mudar pelo inspector do browser, mas ele não regista a mudança quando coloco no custom css do tema (nem no CSS do gravity forms).

Comment: @JonasMarques tente passar alguma outra regra que facilmente se nota, como cor do texto e veja se ocorre alteracao. Provavelmente voce nao esta conseguindo "atingir" o elemento com a regra

Comment: @leofontes, tentei de tudo e não consegui. Entendo que deve estar alguma regra sobrescrevendo, mas não sei o quê nem onde. Estou frustrado: uma coisa tão simples que não consigo resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar a classe do label

```
.gform_wrapper .top_label .gfield_label{
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Depois de alterar e salvar você precisa verificar no inspetor do browser se ele está modificando o tamanho.

Através do link que você colocou não consegui ver sua alteração apenas a do tema padrão.

Com `!important` deveria funcionar.